# zooming on Mapview Crashes the app on iOS6

Tags: xcode, ios6, mkmapview, zooming, didreceivememorywarning

i am using mapview. when i zoomin  on map it shows did recieve memory warning and crashes the app in iOS 6 devices .but its working fine in below versions. Its taking more memory when i zoom in but its not getting released how to release it  i haved deallocated all the objects in deallocation method but it still shows same did receive memory warning and crashes the app 
my code is

```
       mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    [self addSubview:mapView];
    routeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mapView.frame.size.width, mapView.frame.size.height)];
    routeView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [mapView addSubview:routeView];

      - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
       if([annotation isKindOfClass:[TurnAnnotation class]])
{
    MKAnnotationView *turnAnnotationView=[[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil] ;
    turnAnnotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"TurnAnnotation1.png"];

    turnAnnotationView.canShowCallout=NO;
    return turnAnnotationView;
}
else if([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceMark class]])
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];

    if (isdefault==YES) {
        if(!appDel.appBOOL){
            newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            appDel.appBOOL = YES;
        }else {
            newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
            appDel.appBOOL = NO;
        }
    }else{


    if(!appDel.appBOOL){
        newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        appDel.appBOOL = YES;
    }else {
        newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        appDel.appBOOL = NO;
    }
    }

    newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

    return newAnnotation;
}
return nil;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your iOS6 testcase is a Retina version? Retina imagery take up 4x the memory. The low memory warning should notbe ignored..